# How do I make a nested union type's optional member required?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a Typescript type that has an optional member, and I would like to declare a union with that type where that member is always defined:

```
type ItemOptions = { id?: string; };
type Item = ItemOptions & { id: string; };
let myItem: Item = {};  // error, id is required (good!)
x = myItem.id.length;   // don't need a guard, id is never undefined
```

This works fine.  Objects of type `Item` are required to have an `id` member on assignment and I can reference `myItem.id` without a null-guard with `strictNullChecks` enabled.

I can even make a union/intersection hybrid:

```
type ItemOptions = { id?: string; };
type Item = ItemOptions & { id: string; };

let i1: (Item | Item[]) = [{
    id: "1",
}];

if (i1 instanceof Array) {
    let s: string = i1[0].id;
} else {
    let s: string = i1.id;
}
```

This compiles cleanly and both references to the id member are (correctly) treated as always defined. Where it breaks down is trying to make nested union/intersection types work the same way:

```
type ItemOptions = { id?: string; };
type Item = ItemOptions & { id: string; };
type ContainerOptions = { items: ItemOptions | ItemOptions[]; };
type Container = ContainerOptions & { items: Item | Item[]; };

let c1: Container = {
    items: [{
        id: "1",
    }],
};

if (c1.items instanceof Array) {
    let s: string = c1.items[0].id;  // error, id is (string | undefined)
} else {
    let s: string = c1.items.id;  // compiles cleanly, id can't be undefined
}
```

As stated in the comments above, if `c1.items` is not an array, it is treated as an `Item` (id member required), not an `ItemOptions` (id member optional), which is what I want.  But if `c1.items` *is* an array, it is treated as an array of `ItemOptions`, so the id member is treated as optional.

I think I might be doing my union/intersection math a bit wrong here.  What I *want* is to say that `ContainerOptions.items` will always be one object with an optional id member, or an array of such objects, while `Container.items` will always be one object with a required id member, or an array of the same.

Is there a cleaner way to declare this?  Obviously this is a simplified example, in the real code each of these types has many other fields and I'm trying to use unions to avoid repeating myself declaring them.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript compiler thinks (and it isn't really wrong) that something could possibly be both an `Item` and an `ItemOptions[]`: `Item & ItemOptions[]`.  You can probably make such a beast yourself by making a class extending `Array`.  And there's also `Item[] & ItemOptions`.  Let's give those some names:

```
type BeastlyItemOptionsArray = Item & ItemOptions[] 
type BeastlyItemArray = Item[] & ItemOptions
```

If you look at your definition of `Container`, the `items` property has type:

```
Item | (Item[] & ItemOptions[]) | BeastlyItemOptionsArray | BeastlyItemArray
```

When you test if it's an instance of `Array`, it really only eliminates `Item`.  Now it's:

```
(Item[] & ItemOptions[]) | BeastlyItemOptionsArray | BeastlyItemArray
```

And if you access an element on those arrays, you get

```
Item | ItemOptions | Item
```

which is essentially just

```
ItemOptions
```

which is not what you wanted.  Note that if the beastly types were impossible (i.e., `never`) then you'd get what you expect (more or less).

Here's a way to kind of force that to be true: force `ItemOptions` (and therefore `Item`) not to be usable as an array:

```
type ItemOptions = { id?: string; [k: number]: never };
```

Now if you constrain the `items` property of `Container` to an array and access an element you get something like:

```
Item | (ItemOptions & never) | (Item & never)
```

which reduces to

```
Item
```

as you expect and everything compiles.

---

Now a potentially cleaner solution is not to intersect everything together but try to build up your types from reusable pieces.  I don't know your full use case, but maybe something like this:

```
type Item = { id: string }
type ItemOptions = Partial<Item>;
```

You first define `Item` and then use [`Partial<>` from the standard TypeScript library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1317) to make `ItemOptions`.  Then:

```
type MaybeArray<T> = T | T[];
type ProtoContainer = { items: Item };
type Container = {[ K in keyof ProtoContainer]: MaybeArray<ProtoContainer[K]>}
type ContainerOptions = { [K in keyof ProtoContainer]: MaybeArray<Partial<ProtoContainer[K]>>}
```

In this case the `ProtoContainer` represents the basic idea of something with an `items` that holds an `Item`, and `Container` and `ContainerOptions` use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to represent the transformation to the possible-array versions of them.

Does that help?  Good luck!

Comment: I think it's a good start, but I'll probably have to re-read this a few times before it sinks in.  I particularly like the idea of `MaybeArray` -- I didn't define the data structure I'm trying to describe here, and I don't like it, but I think I can manage it with the suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

The excess property checks are not enabled in intersection types. This is a compiler bug and is tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18075

Comment: Wait, does this question have anything to do with excess property checks?  Seems unrelated.